# Share file to all user using an app

Tags: java, android

I am stuck on how to share a file to all user who is using the app I m currently implementing for my FYP. I know I can share file to social media, email, etc. SO is it possible to share file to all user who use my app? I m using firebase as my Database and Android Studio for my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Upload file to server and give that link to the users..

firebase file upload Click[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)